# Parsing new openssh-key-v1 format using openssl libcrypto

Tags: ssh, openssl, private-key, openssh, libcrypto

I need to parse an SSH private key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` with openssl (libcrypto) into a `EVP_PKEY*` or `RSA*` key. Until recently this file would be stored in standard PEM or PKCS1 format which is easy to parse. However openssh has switched to a new format which is more complicated.

The structure is [defined here](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.key?annotate=HEAD) and PEM encoded it looks like this (generated with `ssh-keygen`)

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The first step is to parse the text with `PEM_read_bio` which will strip off the PEM header and base64-decode the data. But it is unclear how to parse the struct from the spec.

The first 15 bytes are fixed as `openssh-key-v1\0` but from there it is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to parse these is to avoid parsing them yourself, and instead use `ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to convert the key into PEM format, and then parse that using OpenSSL as per normal.

If you have a serious desire to get your hands dirty, though, the protocol description you linked to does, in fact, give you *most* of what you need to know.  The (crucial) pieces of missing information are:

- All integers are network byte order;
- `int` is 32 bits;
- Most crucially, the `string` type is a length-value tuple, where `length` is a `uint32` indicating how many of the next octets make up the string; and
- The formats of the various public key types (`ssh-dss`, `ssh-rsa`, `ecdsa-sha2-*`, etc) are documented in various RFCs that you can find referenced in the [IANA registry for SSH Public Key Algorithm Names](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml#ssh-parameters-19).

Extrapolation of the private key portions of various key types is left as an exercise for the reader, because I haven't figured it out yet.  In the (near) future, my [openssl-additions gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/openssl-additions) will have a Ruby-based implementation of [SSH private key parsing](https://github.com/pwnedkeys/openssl-additions/blob/master/lib/openssl/pkey.rb), because I need to figure it out for my own project, so you could take the parameter ordering from that.